# Any tool or plugin to make Django template code smart indention and syntax-highlighting possible?

Tags: django, templates, ide, syntax-highlighting, indentation

I'm new to django, and I'm working on my first google appengine app. I use Pycharm as my IDE.
In my HTML files, **template code** has no **smart-indent and syntax-highlighting**, it looks BAD! Is there any tools or plugins to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try pycharm

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: But I am using Pycharm. Is there any plugin?

Comment: Yes, you r right. It supports django.http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html